# Python best practice: series of "or"s or "in"?

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x

I am working on a [project](https://github.com/johnroper100/CrowdMaster/pull/17) where a question came up about the following line:

```
a == "EQUAL" or a == "NOT EQUAL" or a == "LESS" or a == "GREATER"
```

I proposed a change to make it "simpler" like so:

```
a in ["EQUAL", "NOT EQUAL", "LESS", "GREATER"]
```

What would be considered best practice and what would be best for performance? This is for user interface code that gets updated frequently so minor performance improvements could be noticeable. I know the first example will "fail fast" if any were found, and I am assuming that the second would as well.

Furthermore, wouldn't it be even faster to use a dict like:

```
a in {"EQUAL", "NOT EQUAL", "LESS", "GREATER"}
```

...so that a list wouldn't need to be constructed?

The only thing PEP-8 says (that I could find):

> ...code is read much more often than it is written. The guidelines provided here are intended to improve the readability of code...
>
> However, know when to be inconsistent -- sometimes style guide recommendations just aren't applicable. When in doubt, use your best judgment. Look at other examples and decide what looks best.

Comment: Your `dict` is a `set` but besides that it's a good option.

Comment: @Matthias What would be the problem with a set (other than lack of order which isn't an issue here)?

Comment: There is no problem with a set. Just use it.

Comment: When in doubt, `timeit`

Comment: What happens after `self.Operation in ...`?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I left out the *if* statement b/c it is not relevant for this Q, but it would be `if self.operation in [...]: do something`.

Comment: The `do something` is what I was asking about. If you called a method you could map the methods to the names and do it all in one step

Comment: @PadraicCunningham It is a single line of UI code: `layout.prop(self, "Value")` that will be the same regardless of which one `self.operation` was.

Comment: Note that on top of the overhead from checking each `==`, the chained `or`s also have to lookup the object overtime. It's fine if you have just `a == "EQUAL"`, but in your initial version you had `self.Operation == "EQUAL"` - depending on how complex objects are, repeated lookups can be costly *in  critical code sections*.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Yes, I was just trying to make it more universal with the `a`.

Comment: Related question, better to use `in []` or `in {}`? I know sets are built for this, but not clear (to me) they will be faster for such small inputs?

Comment: @Chris_Rands In general, `set` is better: either it is faster, or your data is so small that it doesn't matter. So using `set` as a default is a good idea.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Thanks, I was thinking in the context of the comments ShadowRanger made on this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39453423/how-to-delete-a-character-from-sublist-in-python-resolving-errors/39453627#39453627

Comment: This situation is *exactly* what Knuth was talking about when he said, "Premature optimization is the root of all evil." Do something simple and readable. If it blows up into a performance problem, profile it. If the particular check you wrote here proves to be the bottleneck, *then* worry about it. Write clean code, then optimize as needed. (And those optimizations might make it a bit more messy.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd go with the set. It's much more readable. The string of `or`s can be faster in some circumstances since the operator short circuits and there is no overhead of constructing the list of items each time but I don't think it's worth the readability sacrifice. Here is a quick and dirty benchmark. This is with Python 2.7

```
 def t1(x):
   return (x == "Foo" or x == "Bar" or x == "Baz" or x == "Quux")                                                                                    


 def t2(x):
   return x in {"Foo", "Bar", "Baz", "Quux"}

 [2.7.9]>>> import timeit
 [2.7.9]>>> timeit.timeit(lambda : t1("Quux"))                                                                                                                  
 0.22514700889587402
 [2.7.9]>>> timeit.timeit(lambda : t1("Foo"))                                                                                                                   
 0.18890380859375
 [2.7.9]>>> timeit.timeit(lambda : t2("Quux"))                                                                                                                  
 0.27969884872436523
 [2.7.9]>>> timeit.timeit(lambda : t2("Foo"))                                                                                                                   
 0.25904297828674316
```

Python 3 numbers.

```
 [3.4.2]>>> timeit.timeit(lambda : t1("Quux"))
 0.25126787397312
 [3.4.2]>>> timeit.timeit(lambda : t1("Foo"))
 0.1722603400121443
 [3.4.2]>>> timeit.timeit(lambda : t2("Quux"))
 0.18982669000979513
 [3.4.2]>>> timeit.timeit(lambda : t2("Foo"))
 0.17984321201220155
```

Comment: Would be interesting to see how long it takes when the item is *not* valid, e.g. `"foobar"`.

Comment: The set version is much more competitive in later versions of python. In python2 the set is rebuilt each time. In later versions, since the set is never mutated, the compiler creates a frozenset at compile time and caches it.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously in your case it's better to use `in` operator. It's just much more readable.

In more complex cases when it's not possible to use `in` operator, you may use [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) and [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) functions:

```
operations = {'EQUAL', 'NOT EQUAL', 'LESS', 'GREATER'}
condition1 = any(curr_op.startswith(op) for op in operations)

condition2 = all([
    self.Operation == "EQUAL",
    isinstance(self.LeftHandSide, int),
    isinstance(self.RightHandSide, int),
])
```

Comment: This would be worse than any approach as you are evaluating everything every time. any is also slow regardless.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham it won't if you use generators.

Comment: Yes but you weren't until you edited and the second all still is in a list  so you still evaluate all of them each time.

Comment: `any` and `all` will short-circuit, so they have similar optimizations as `and` and `or`. That's only relevant when feeding them generators, though. `all([...` still has the entire list built.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham "Yes but you weren't until you edited." - thanks for pointing that out! :)

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, these functions show your intent, sometimes it's much better than a long chain of `or`s and `and`s.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, just help me to come up with a better example of `all` usage ;)

Comment: @skovorodkin Fully agree, your use for `any` is a very nice example. That one would even survive subclassing/parameterization with more `operations`, which `or` does not.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by multiple people, go for reability.

performance wise there is a difference, the `in` operator on sets has an average lookup time of O(1), while for lists it's O(n). You can find this [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity).

In your case where the list of possibilities is limited you will hardly notice a difference. However, once this list becomes very large (talking about millions), you can notice a difference.

A simple example can show this: For sets:

```
operation = 9999999
lookupSet = {i for i in range(0,10000000)}
%timeit operation in lookupSet
>> 10000000 loops, best of 3: 89.4 ns per loop
```

where with lists:

```
operation = 9999999
lookupList =  [i for i in range(0,10000000)]
%timeit operation in lookupList
>> 10 loops, best of 3: 168 ms per loop
```